# How to create a second Qt .ui form?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qt-designer

I want to make a 2 windows application (one window has a button that opens the second window in the previous window)

So far, I've got this:

1. login.h
2. login.cpp
3. login.ui
4. mainwindow.h (no errors here for sure, that's why I did not attach this)
5. mainwindow.cpp (no errors here for sure, that's why I did not attach this)
6. mainwindow.ui (no errors here for sure, that's why I did not attach this)

login.h:

```cpp
class MainWindow2: public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow2(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow2();

private:
    MainWindow2 *ui;
};
```

login.cpp:

```
MainWindow2::MainWindow2(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent), ui(new MainWindow2)
{

    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow2::~MainWindow2()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

To be exact, I've got an error in the login.cpp, the error is:

> no member named setupUi in MainWindow2

.pro file:

```
    #-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2019-06-21T16:44:15
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui network

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = untitled3
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += \
        login.cpp \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
        login.h \
        mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
        login.ui \
        mainwindow.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195381/discussion-on-question-by-lucifer-how-to-create-second-qt-ui-form).

Answer (score 1):

In Qt Creator 5.8 at first you need to add form into your project (*.pro):

[image: add new form to Qt]

Then, in the first form's header, include the second form's header. Then you can declare and initialize a pointer type of the second form in the first form:

```cpp
Form2 m_pSecondWnd = new Form
```

And on button click, create a slot in the first form:

```cpp
this->close();
m_pSecondWnd ->show();
```

Answer (score 0):

> "no member named setupUi in "class"

> "allocation of incomplete type "UI::class"

Such errors are caused by creating only Qt Designer forms (Qt Designer did not create `.h` file, only `.ui`).

You have to create a Qt Designer Form Class, in order for `.h` and `.ui` files to be created. And don't forget to `#include` it, for example, `#include "ui_mainwindow.h"`.